# restrict character length to display in jquery table with handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

How do i restrict the characters to display with my jqurty table that gets populated from `Handlerbars.Compile`

```
Handlebars.compile('<tr><td>{{productDescription}}</td></tr>')
```

I want to display only first 10 characters and want to show `...` which if the user clicks on should invoke a jqueryui dialog that shows the entire product description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Handlebars helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('dotdotdot', function(str) {
  if (str.length > 10)
    return str.substring(0,10) + '...';
  return str;
});
```

After that, in your template write

```
{{dotdotdot productDescription}}
```

Comment: Love your function’s name.